# Acoustic Echo Cancellation(AEC) on mobile with Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: ios, flash, flash-builder, microphone, aec

It is told that AEC not available on mobile. But I noticed that [Adobe Connect](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobeconnect.html) application is able to do echo cancellation on ipad.

How that can be **possible**?

I tried sdk 4.6 air sdk 3.2 but `Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone()` returns *null*.
`Microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true)` also doesn't help.